# How to fetch data from drop-down menu in PHP?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to select multiple elements from a drop down menu bar and show it in the next text box without submitting the form?

Suppose I have elements like "car,dog,rat,bike,tv,fridge,etc,etc " showing in the drop down menu. I want to select car,bike,tv,fridge and fetch the data in the next text area without going to a new page i.e I want to show the user selected items but only from drop down box only.

Comment: Share what you have tried

Comment: I havent tried anything yet.

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service, give it a try yourself and edit your question to include your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you want

```
<select id="select" multiple>
    <option value="1">car</option>
    <option value="2">dog</option>
    <option value="3">rat</option>
    <option value="4">bike</option>
</select>


<textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
```

your js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "#txt1" ).text( str );
  })
  .change();
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fsmsnnmp/)**

**Do not forget to include jquery.js file**

Answer (score 0):

Welcome To StackOverflow! As stated in the comments, for a better answer try providing what you have already as there are multiple ways to answer this type of question.

Having said that, this should help:

```js
$('.dropdown').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(".dropdown").val();
  $('textarea').val(value); //insert string into textarea
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dropdown" multiple>
  <option>Rock</option>
  <option>Paper</option>
  <option>Scissors</option>
  <option>Lizard</option>
  <option>Spock</option>
</select>
<textarea></textarea>
```

This is using jQuery, so remember to include the jQuery file.

Comment: I think slight modification has to be done in your code.. u need to add change function of select.. not as soon as Dom loads..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Thanks for the feedback, I've changed my code to cater for this.